# Comparing unicode code tick mark values

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, character-encoding

I'm using Unicode value '✔' to display a tick mark in text area.

Now I need to fetch the value in text area and need to check whether symbol is present in that?

When I'm fetching the text area value I'm getting a checkbox without tick like symbol instead of tick symbol.

How can I compare this Unicode value is exist or not?

```
// Not working.
if( document.getElementById('location').value.charAt(0) == '&#10004')
    alert("symbol');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that `&#10004;` is an HTML entity that represents **✔** in HTML but it is just a string in JavaScript. In JavaScript you'd want `'✔'` (the raw character) or `'\u2714'`:

```
if(document.getElementById('location').value.charAt(0) == '\u2714')
    alert("symbol");
else
    alert("not there");
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WCdCg/

The HTML `&#....;` notation uses decimal numbers, the JavaScript `'\u....'` notation uses hexadecimal. Converting 10004 to hexadecimal yields 2714. You can also use `&#x....;` in HTML if you want to use hexadecimal there as well, for example `&#x2714;` is ✔. Using just hexadecimal is probably easier than dealing with the base conversions.

Comment: thank u so much worked exaclty i want , can i get correponding value for &#9829; also

Comment: @user976034: The HTML `&#...;` notation uses decimal, the JavaScript `'\u...'` uses hex so you'd want `'\u2665'` for `&#9829;`.

Comment: @user976034: I updated my answer with some clarification on the numbers used in the various notations.